# Remove Decimal for cart summary

Tags: magento2

remove decimal from price on cart summry page in mgento2

Comment: do you want to remove only from cart summary area ? and cart summary on checkout page ?

Comment: yes i want to remove on cart summary page which show on side

Comment: i succesfullly remove from plp page but not works on cart summary pagae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change price decimal you have to override and change **getFormattedPrice()** defined in `/Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js` .

However you can also use [Lillik Price Decimal](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal) free extension, which will remove decimal value from all places ( i.e detail page, listing page, cart view page, cart summary and total etc ).

Comment: yes i used that extenssion but not remove cart summary page

Comment: i think it does, i had tested that too however you can opt js solution then.